# Click to copy contents of innerHTML textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

Recently I wrote a bit of code that is later going to be used as a random string/number generator. The strings generate inside of a read-only text field via. innerHTML. I wanted to add a click to copy button allowing users to easily copy generated strings, and have started playing around with ZeroClipboard. I was wondering if anyone could point me into the right direction if I wanted to copy the randomly generated string via. ZeroClipboard, as I have had a bit of trouble trying to combine the codes.

Thanks!

Random String Generation Code:

Live example featured here: http://hawkgen.com/gen/

```
   <!-- The first select list -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons-core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forms-r.css">
    <center>
    <form class="pure-form">
    <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
     <option>- - -</option>
     <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
     <option value="apple">Apple</option>
     <option value="keurig">Keurig</option>
     <option value="nike">Nike</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
    <span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>
    <div
    <form class="pure-form">
    <input type="text" value="Code" readonly id="display">
    </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="SList.getSelect('scontent','go');" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" value="Generate">
    </center>
    </form>

  <script>
    var choice2;
    function setChoice(value) {
        choice2 = value;

    }
    /* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
    var SList = new Object();             // JS object that stores data for options

    // HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
    var txtsl2 = '';

    /*
     Property with options for the Seccond select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the first select
     The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond select
    */
    SList.slist2 = {
     "amazon": ['Kindle Fire HD', 'Kindle Charger', 'Kindle Fire HDX'],
     "apple": ['MacBook', 'iMac', 'iPhone', 'iPad'],
     "keurig": ['Platinum', 'Vue'],
     "nike": ['Fuel Band']
    };


    /*
     Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
     The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
     The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
    */

SList.scontent = {
 "Kindle Fire HD": 'kindlefirehd',
 "Kindle Charger": 'kindlecharge',
 "Kindle Fire HDX": 'kindlefirehdx',
 "MacBook": 'macbook',
 "iMac": 'imac',
 "iPhone": 'iphone',
 "iPad": 'ipad',
 "Platinum": 'platinum',
 "Vue": 'vue',
 "FuelBand": 'fuelband'
};





        /* From here no need to modify */

    // function to get the dropdown list, or content
    SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
        if (option == 'go') {
            option = choice2;
        }
      document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';           // empty option-content

      if(SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if(slist == 'scontent'){;
var selected = SList[slist][option];
functions[selected]();
}
        else if(slist == 'slist2') {
          var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
          for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
            addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
          }

          document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="setChoice(this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
        }
      }
      else if(slist == 'slist2') {
        // empty the tag for 2nd select list
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    var functions = {

        kindlefirehd: function(){
    var secondPossible = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSVWY123456';
    var firstPossible = '123456';
    var firstLength = 1;
    var secondLength = 2;

    var firstString = Array.apply(null, new Array(firstLength)).map(function () {
    return firstPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstPossible.length)];
    }).join('');
    var secondString = Array.apply(null, new Array(secondLength)).map(function () {
    return secondPossible[Math.floor(Math.random() * secondPossible.length)];
    }).join('');

    document.getElementById("display").value='D0FB A0A0 343' + firstString + ' 0A' + secondString

        },
        kindlecharge: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        kindlefirehdx: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        macbook: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        imac: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        iphone: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        ipad: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        platinum: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        vue: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        fuelband: function(){window.alert("func1 called")}
    }





    </script>
```

ZeroClipboard code:

Live example here: http://hawkgen.com/ZeroClipboard/

```
<html>
  <body>
<button id="target-to-copy" data-clipboard-target="clipboard-text">Click To Copy</button>
<input name="clipboard-text" id="clipboard-text" value="clipboardtesttext">

    <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So was your Google Analytics code really pertinent to the question ?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to take it out.